# In C++ is there an idiomatic way to guard against the situation in which running a collection of actions causes the collection to be mutated?

Tags: c++, raii

Say you have a class `foo` that wraps a collection of some kind of callable objects. `foo` has a member function `run()` that iterates over the collection and calls each function object. `foo` also has a member `remove(...)` that will remove a callable object from the collection.

Is there an idiomatic, RAII-style guard you can put in `foo.run()` and `foo.remove(...)` such that the removes that were driven by a call to `foo.run()` 
 will be deferred until the guard's destructor fires? Can it be done with something in the standard library? Does this pattern have a name?

My current code seems inelegant so am looking for a best practice type solution.

Note: this is isnt about concurrency. A non thread-safe solution is fine. The issue is with re-entrancy and self-reference.

Here is an example of the problem, sans the inelegant "defer remove" guard.

```
class ActionPlayer
{
private:
    std::vector<std::pair<int, std::function<void()>>> actions_;
public:
    void addAction(int id, const std::function<void()>& action)
    {
        actions_.push_back({ id, action });
    }

    void removeAction(int id)
    {
        actions_.erase(
            std::remove_if(
                actions_.begin(),
                actions_.end(),
                [id](auto& p) { return p.first == id; }
            ),
            actions_.end()
        );
    }

    void run()
    {
        for (auto& item : actions_) {
            item.second();
        }
    }
};
```

then elsewhere:

```
...

ActionPlayer player;

player.addAction(1, []() {
    std::cout << "Hello there" << std::endl;
});

player.addAction(42, [&player]() {
    std::cout << "foobar" << std::endl;
    player.removeAction(1);
});

player.run(); // boom
```

Edit ... okay this is how I can see to do this via an RAII lock object. The following should handle actions throwing and re-entrant calls to run within run assuming the recursion eventually terminates (if not that is the user's fault). I used cached std::functions because in the real version of this code the equivalent of addAction and removeAction are template functions which cant just be stored in a vanilla homogeneously typed container.

```
class ActionPlayer
{
private:

    std::vector<std::pair<int, std::function<void()>>> actions_;
    int run_lock_count_;
    std::vector<std::function<void()>> deferred_ops_;

    class RunLock
    {
    private:
        ActionPlayer* parent_;
    public:
        RunLock(ActionPlayer* parent) : parent_(parent) { (parent_->run_lock_count_)++; }
        ~RunLock()
        {
            if (--parent_->run_lock_count_ == 0) {
                while (!parent_->deferred_ops_.empty()) {
                    auto do_deferred_op = parent_->deferred_ops_.back();
                    parent_->deferred_ops_.pop_back();
                    do_deferred_op();
                }
            }
        }
    };

    bool isFiring() const
    {
        return run_lock_count_ > 0;
    }

public:
    ActionPlayer() : run_lock_count_(0)
    {
    }

    void addAction(int id, const std::function<void()>& action)
    {
        if (!isFiring()) {
            actions_.push_back({ id, action });
        } else {
            deferred_ops_.push_back(
                [&]() {
                    addAction(id, action);
                }
            );
        }
    }

    void removeAction(int id)
    {
        if (!isFiring()) {
            actions_.erase(
                std::remove_if(
                    actions_.begin(),
                    actions_.end(),
                    [id](auto& p) { return p.first == id; }
                ),
                actions_.end()
            );
        } else {
            deferred_ops_.push_back(
                [&]() {
                    removeAction(id); 
                }
            );
        }
    }

    void run()
    {
        RunLock lock(this);
        for (auto& item : actions_) {
            item.second();
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Why don't you show your "inelegant 'defer remove' guard"?  That sounds like the way I'd approach it.

Comment: Because I have it in my real code not this toy version and it is tied to the real structures which use variadic templates etc. That is in a sense the problem. I was trying to find a more generic solution not one that needs to know about the internals of ActionPlayer-like classes. Anyway, ill update the example when I get some time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a flag to `run` that says you're enumerating thru `actions_`.  Then if `removeAction` is called with that flag set, you store the `id` in a vector for later removal.  You might also need a separate vector to hold actions that are added while enumerating.  Once you're all done iterating thru `actions_`, you remove the ones that want removed and add the ones that got added.

Something like

```
// within class ActionPlayer, add these private member variables
private:
    bool running = false;
    std::vector<int> idsToDelete;

public:
    void run() {
        running = true;
        for (auto& item : actions_) {
            item.second();
        }
        running = false;
        for (d: idsToDelete)
            removeAction(d);
        idsToDelete.clear();
    }

    // ...
```

You can make a similar change for deferred `addAction` calls (which you'll need to do if any of the actions can add an action, since the add might cause the vector to allocate more storage, invalidating all iterators to the vector).

Comment: if one of the actions throws you'll be left in an indeterminant state though.

Comment: @jwezorek: so put it in try/catch or use `unique_ptr<T, function<void>>` for automatic cleanup

Answer (score 1):

Usual way is to create a copy of the `vector`. But this may cause the removed actions to be run again.

```
void run()
{
    auto actions_copy{actions_};
    for (auto& item : actions_copy) {
        item.second();
    }
}
```

Other options if running removed action is not allowed

1. Add a bool to store if some action is removed
2. Use shared/weak ptr
3. use `std::list` if it is known that the current action will not be removed.

Comment: hmmm ... copying is simple but I was hoping for something that doesnt allocate memory in run() in the majority of cases in which a self-referential remove does not happen. 

I don't think just switching to an std::list fixes the problem

Comment: Then you should go with adding a `bool` to store if an action is marked as removed and remove them at the end of `run`

Answer (score 0):

I would modify the structure slightly. Instead of allowing `ActionPlayer` to be modified directly, I would force all modifications through an external modifier class. In this example I made it an abstract Modifier class which can have different concrete implementations (e.g. `DeferredModifier`, `InstantModifier`, `NullModifier`, `LoggedModifier`, `TestModifier` .etc.). Your actions now only need to take a reference to the abstract base class of a modifier and call any add/remove .etc. function on that as necessary.. This allows separation of modification policy from the action implementation, and injection of different modification policies into actions.

This should also allow simpler support for concurrent modification, as you no longer need to toggle the run /  not running state to defer modifications.

This example shows a simple way of replaying the actions in order (which is a property I assume you want to maintain). A more advanced implementation could scan the modification list backwards removing all add/remove pairs and then group modifications / removals to minimise copying when modifying the actions list.

Something like:

```
class ActionPlayer {
friend class Modifier;
...

    void run(Modifier &modifier) { }
private:
    void addAction(...) { ... }
    void removeAction(...) { ... }
}

class Modifier
{
public:
    virtual ~Modifier() {}
    virtual addAction(...) = 0;
    virtual removeAction(...) = 0;
}

class DelayedModifier : public Modifier
{
    struct Modification { virtual void run(ActionPlayer&) = 0; }

    struct RemoveAction : public Modification
    {
        int id;

        Removal(int _id) : id(_id) {} 
        virtual void run(ActionPlayer &player) { player.removeAction(id); }
    }

    struct AddAction : public Modification
    {
        int id;
        std::function<void(Modifier&)>> action;

        AddAction(int _id, const std::function<void(Modifier&)> &_action) : id(_id), action(_action)  {}
        virtual void run(ActionPlayer &player) { player.addAction(id, action) };
    }

    ActionPlayer &player;
    std::vector<Modification> modifications;

public:
    DelayedModifier(ActionPlayer &_player) player(_player) {}
    virtual ~DelayedModifier() { run(); }

    virtual void addAction(int id, const std::function<void(Modifier&)> &action) { modifications.push_back(AddAction(id, action)); }
    virtual void removeAction(int id) { modifications.push_back(RemoveAction(id)); }

    void run()
    {
        for (auto &modification : modifications)
            modification.run(player);
        modifications.clear();
    }
};
```

So you now write:

```
ActionPlayer player;

{
    DelayedModifier modifier(player);

    modifier.addAction(...);
    modifier.addAction(...);
    modifier.run();
    actions.run(modifier);
}
```